# Handling month in switch case PHP

Tags: php, loops, switch-statement

I want to get the current month and add the next three months and show it in my table header.

The code I have is:

```
    $mon = (date('M')); 
    switch($mon) {
    case 'Mar' :  
    echo  '<th>Mar</th>';
    echo  '<th>Apr</th>';
    echo  '<th>May</th>';
    break;
    case 'Apr' :  
    echo  '<th>Apr</th>';
    echo  '<th>May</th>';
    echo  '<th>Jun</th>';
    break;
    }

    ............... and so on ..............
```

The above switch case will do its job for all the twelve months.
Is there any way to do it dynamically with a single switch case for all the twelve months rather than having 12 switch cases?
Am I running mad?

Thanks,
Kimz

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Populating an array with the names of the next 12 months](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215555/php-populating-an-array-with-the-names-of-the-next-12-months)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also calculate the next months on your own:

```
$now = time();
$currentMonth = date('n', $now);
$year = date('Y', $now);
$nextMonth = $currentMonth + 1;
$secondNextMonth = $currentMonth + 2;

echo  '<th>' . date('M', $now) . '</th>';
echo  '<th>' . date('M', mktime(0, 0, 0, $nextMonth, 1, $year)) . '</th>';
echo  '<th>' . date('M', mktime(0, 0, 0, $secondNextMonth, 1, $year)) . '</th>';
```

Comment: `mktime` will actually wrap around on its own, you don't need to reset back to `1`. In fact you have a bug in that code and will get January twice in December. Apart from that, good solution.

Comment: I thought you were talking about the day parameter. I adjusted the code according to your suggestion. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just print the values directly?

```
<?php
echo '<th>'.date('M').'</th>';
echo '<th>'.date('M',strtotime("+1 months")).'</th>';
echo '<th>'.date('M',strtotime("+2 months")).'</th>';
```

Comment: This may give you wrong results on, say, January 31st. "+1 months" is somewhat fickle since "1 month" is a vague specification.

Answer (score 0):

You could use strtotime to get the next months:

```
echo  '<th>' . date('M') . '</th>';
echo  '<th>' . date('M', strtotime('+1 months')) . '</th>';
echo  '<th>' . date('M', strtotime('+2 months')) . '</th>';
```

Comment: This may give you wrong results on, say, January 31st. "+1 months" is somewhat fickle since "1 month" is a vague specification.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple code easy to understand. Try it out

```
$month = array('Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec');
for($i=0;$i<=11;$i++)
{
    if(date('M') == $month[$i])
    {
        $a = $i + 1;
        $b = $i + 2;
        if($a > 11)
        {
            $a = 0;
            $b = 1;
        }
        if($b > 11)
        {
            $b = 0;
        }
        echo  '<th>' . $month[$i] . '</th>';
        echo  '<th>' . $month[$a] . '</th>';
        echo  '<th>' . $month[$b] . '</th>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Easy to understand? Maybe. Simple? Not really. ;)

Comment: @deceze It may not be simple for everyone , but for u it is. I checked your stackoverflow profile ;-) it should be a walk in the park for you  :-D

Comment: Not saying I don't understand it, on the contrary. I'm saying it's overly complicated, not "simple". :) For me "simple" means "concise, not verbose".

Comment: @deceze Yup i got that from the ';-)' after Not really. I was just pulling your leg ;-) :-)