# How to list the last N months with PHP DateTime

Tags: php, datetime

I want to populate a select input with the last 5 months (including the current month). So on 09/04/2014 the options should look something like this:

```
April 2014
March 2014
February 2014
January 2014
December 2013
```

My first solution with PHP DateTime seemed to work:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
 $date = new DateTime($i.' months ago');
 echo $date->format('F Y'); //populate select input
}
```

But in fact it doesn't handle edge cases. For example, on 31/03/2014 it produces:

```
March 2014
March 2014
January 2014
December 2013
December 2013
```

What is the correct way to list the last 10 months with PHP DateTime?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Populating an array with the names of the next 12 months](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215555/php-populating-an-array-with-the-names-of-the-next-12-months) (just in reverse)

Comment: @deceze - while I'm happy to look at alternative solutions, your link does not show a solution with DateTime.

Comment: Why does it have to be `DateTime`? `mktime` is a lot better suited for this procedure.

Comment: @deceze - see [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/#date_and_time). strtotime for example has limitations with dates after 2038.

Comment: If the system your code is running on in 2038 is still susceptible to the Y2K38 problem, your code will probably be falling apart somewhere anyway, regardless of this particular coding question. I can't see UNIX timestamps going away completely, so this problem will have to be solved on virtually all systems. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting same 2 months, because when you are subtracting 1 month from date, that has more days than previous month. Example: when you subtract 1 month from 31.3. you will get 3.3. (same month), and not 28.2. as you might expect...

My suggestion is to get first day of current month, and then do your logic:

```php
$dt = new DateTime('first day of this month');
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    echo $dt->format('F Y'), "\n";
    $dt->modify('-1 month');
}
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/130054)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

```
$date = new DateTime("2014/03/31");
for ($i = 0; $i <= 9; $i++) {
    $date->modify("-1 month");
    echo $date->format('F Y'); //populate select input
}
```

Comment: thanks. Is there any documentation on the different behaviour between "-1 month" and "1 month ago."?

Comment: Yes you can find more here
http://it1.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php